# How can i implement auto scale feature in nifty-gui?

Tags: nifty-gui

As I can see in [this](http://vimeo.com/31332260) vimeo video there's a nice feature to scale the whole interface but I cannot find any documentation anywhere telling me how can I do it ( nor in the 1.3.2 manual ).

Answer (score 1):

You enable it on the Nifty instance using a "base resolution". This "base resolution" will be used as the inital size of your gui and when it is enabled the actual gui will be scaled automatically to the actual screen resolution:

```
nifty.enableAutoScaling(1024, 768);
```

Another way to use it, is to set a "base resolution" and provide the scale factors for width and height directly:

```
nifty.enableAutoScaling(1024, 768, 2.0, 2.0);
```

See the [Nifty](https://github.com/void256/nifty-gui/blob/1.3/nifty-core/src/main/java/de/lessvoid/nifty/Nifty.java#L1559) class for reference and there is an [example](https://github.com/void256/nifty-gui/blob/1.3/nifty-examples/src/main/java/de/lessvoid/nifty/examples/defaultcontrols/ControlsDemoScreenController.java#L230) available as well.